# Is there shorthand for casting to an object, and getting a value

Tags: c#

I need to cast a generic object to `XmlNode[]` so I can get the value with `.Value`

Since `x` is only a temporary variable, is there a way to accomplish this in 1 line of code?

```
var x = (XmlNode[])car.title;
car.title = x[0].Value;
```

Comment: Note that the compiler may optimize and inline this anyway. Unless you have something against explicit code, I wouldn't bother

Comment: If you declare title `dynamic` then you don't need a cast at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put both lines together like this:

```csharp
car.title = ((XmlNode[])car.title)[0].Value;
```

Of course, if that's easier to read is a preference thing.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @KidBilly just think about arithmetic, with ```( )``` you can dictate what should be evaluated first. This way you could even chain multiple instructions in a single line, though, remember you eventually sacrifice readability

Comment: @Tomek Makes sense.  I will try to remember that about `( )`